# Can a django templatetag invoke a view function directly? i want to use "include tag" with form data from another app

Tags: python, django

all, can a django templatetag invoke a view function directly? i want to use "include html" tags with form data from another app.

My project structure like below:

```
ProjectRoot
├── manage.py
├── MyProject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── templates
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── contact-us.html
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── tags_form.html
│   ├── tags_index.html
├── app_1
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templatetags
│   │   ├── __init__.py.bak
│   │   └── app1_tags.py.bak
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── app_2
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templatetags
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── app2_tags.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
```

i want to use "{% include app2.html%}" in app_1.html to access the app_2.html content which belongs to app_2, and the app_2.html contained form data belongs app_2/views(forms).

at the same, the "included" app_2.html which would be shown in app_1.html has a 'submit' POST operation, i need to retrieve the posted data as well. the code in app_2/ folder like below:

app_2/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

app_name = 'Test_Example'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^logexplorertest/', views.index, name='index'),
    ]
```

app_2/views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import MyForm
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

import subprocess
basePath="/var/log/"

@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            getPostList=request.POST.getlist('field')
            tailedLines=[]
            listCmd = subprocess.Popen(["tail -n 10 %s%s"%(basePath,getPostList[0])], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
            fileTailLastLines = listCmd.read().splitlines()
            for line in fileTailLastLines:
                tailedLines.append('\n%s'%str(line, encoding = "utf-8"))
            print ("Log file content has been retrieved and printed like on the screen." )
            return render(request, 'logexplorer_index.html', {'form': form,'tailedLines':tailedLines})
    else:
        form = MyForm()
        return render(request, 'logexplorer_index.html', {'form':form})
```

app_2/forms.py:

```
from django import forms
import subprocess
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

basePath="/var/log/"
fileList=[]

def fileListCollect():
    listCmd = subprocess.Popen(["ls -l %s| awk '{print $9}'"%basePath], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
    outPutsReader = listCmd.read().splitlines()
    for line in outPutsReader:
        fileList.append([str(line, encoding = "utf-8"),str(line, encoding = "utf-8")])
    return tuple(fileList)

class MyForm(forms.Form):  
    field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=fileListCollect(),label='Text file to retrieve')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here, but I think you are looking for [jnclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

Comment: yes. in fact, i am not very sure which is the proper or easier way to invoke view functions crossing the site. i only want to access app_2/views.py functions in app_1 (get better to be in app_1 html templates directly)

Comment: The only thing that should invoke a view function is a URL.

Comment: you mean {%url "Upgrade_Example:index" %} or path, or redirect? if so, the whole page would "jump" to another new page.

Comment: No that's not what I said at all. I said you need to use inclusion tags, not views, because views can only be called by URLs.

Comment: thanks, can you tell me how to use inclusion_tags to render forms context to html template, and then retrieve data by submit btn crossing the site?

Comment: i've tried the code below, but can NOT retrieve data after submit-btn clicking: 
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.template.defaulttags import csrf_token


@register.inclusion_tag('tags_form.html',takes_context=True)
def say_forms(context):
    form_test=forms.MyForm()
    context = {
        'form' : form_test,
        }
    return context

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding:
context['request']